# Show that $\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n)}\sim n^k$ for large values of n

Tags: limits, gamma-function

In order to prove the above result I proceeded as follows:

We know that:

> $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)\Gamma(n-1)$

Using this fact, we have:
$\Gamma(n+k)=(n+k-1)\Gamma(n+k-1)\\=(n+k-1)(n+k-2)\Gamma(n+k-2)\\
=...=(n+k-1)(n+k-2)...(n+k-k)\Gamma(n+k-k)\\=n(n+1)...(n+k-1)\Gamma(n)$

So, now we have:
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n)}=
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n)}$$

Now, if $x$ is a variable and $c$ is a constant, then

> $x+c\approx x$ (for very large values of $x$) (*I am a little doubtful about this*)

Using this fact, can we say that:
$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n)}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}n(n+1)...(n+k-1)\\\sim n.n...n\ (k\ times)\\=n^k$

Thus, we have:
$$\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n)}\sim n^k$$

Is this method valid? Is there a more *"mathematically rigorous"* way to prove this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It can't possibly be the limit equals what you say as the variable $\;n\;$ is tending to $\;\infty\;$ : it cannot appear in the result!

Comment: @Joanpemo Thanks for pointing that out. What I meant was $\approx$. Going to correct it now.

Comment: Is $k\geq 0$ and an integer? This is important, because if $k=-1$ then you will find that the answer is 0 (namely $1/\infty$), and if $k=1/2$ then the gammas do not cancel out to each other.

Comment: Yes, $k\geqslant 0$ but not necessarily an *integer*

Comment: @Jasper Yes, I believe that if $k=1/2$, the gammas will not cancel (as a matter of fact I think that the gammas will not cancel for any fractions). But if I only want an approximate result will it still be true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to prove an approximation
$$
\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n)}\approx n^k
$$
prove the more precise [asymptotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis):
$$
\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n)}\sim n^k
$$
where by definition
$$
f(x) \sim g(x) \quad\text{iff}\quad \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1
$$
With this, your proof works fine, because
$$
n(n+1)\cdots(n+k-1) \sim n^k
$$

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) says that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)n^{\alpha}} = 1 \quad\text{for all } \alpha\in\mathbf{R},$$
which means that
$$
\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)}\sim n^\alpha
$$
but the proof is likely to be different from the one above.

Comment: Do you think the formula would be good even for (positive) fractional values of k?

Comment: @KaustavSen What does $\approx$ mean?

Comment: @Did In this case $\approx$ would means that the error between the true value and the value obtained using the simplified formula must be negligible as we increase $n$

Comment: @KaustavSen "Negligible" how? You say that $x_n\approx y_n$ if $x_n-y_n\to0$?

Comment: @Did Yes, as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: @Did as lhf mentioned a more appropriate notation would be to replace $\approx$ by $\sim$.

Comment: @KaustavSen Then $\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n)}\approx n^k$ is wrong (say, for every $k>1$). As is your $x+c\approx x$ in the question (except if $c=0$).

Comment: @Did As mentioned earlier a more appropriate notation would be: $\frac{\Gamma(n-k)}{\Gamma(n)}\sim n^k$. Similarly, $x+c \sim x$

Comment: @Kaustav The trouble is that your question used (and still uses) the $\approx$ relation, for which I know no definition, and for which it seems now that you know no definition either. Needless to say, the $\sim$ relation is perfectly well defined. If the experience could lead you to abandon the former for the latter... A last note: $a_n\sim b_n$ DOES NOT mean that $a_n-b_n\to0$.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the advice. I have now made the required changes in the question above. However, I was wondering that you mean to say that the symbol $\approx$ has no real meaning?

Comment: @Kaustav You used it with no definition in mind. It is widely used on the site, inconsistently, by users who seem to have no precise definition in mind. The canonical WP page on asymptotics notations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation does not mention it. Mathematicians do not use it... These are some reasons why I saw fit to inform you that the symbol $\approx$ has no real, unambiguous, firm, meaning.